# java catching exceptions

Tags: java

```
    try {
        if (x.length == Styles.size()) {

        }
        else{
             throws InputMismatchException ;
        }
    } finally {
        OutputFileScanner.close();
    }
```

I get compile error in method contains code above , is there any way to throw InputMismatchException in else block ?

Comment: It's probably just complaining that you haven't declared that your function is possible of throwing the InputMismatchException.  Try adding "throws InputMismatchException" to the end of your function definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword:

```
throw new InputMismatchException();
```

Comment: All these "declare `throws`" answers and everything, sheesh, I thought I was going to have to answer this one. `InputMismatchException` isn't even a checked exception, it's a subclass of `RuntimeException`. +1

Comment: Yep, left the `RuntimeException` bit out as the OP probably isn't declaring it anyway (or at least _shouldnt_ be).

Answer (score 1):

A "throws" declaration doesn't go in the method body. If you want to simply throw the Exception, declare it as follows:

```
    public void method() throws InputMismatchException{

    if(...) {...
     OutputFileScanner.close();
   }
    else{
      OutputFileScanner.close();
     throw new InputMismatchException("Uh oh");
      }
    }
```

There's no need to use a try statement here. When you call method(), you will use the following:

```
try{
  method();
} catch (InputMismatchException ime){
   //do what you want
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the method it lives in to throw the exception.

Because `OutputStream.close()` throws `IOException` you'll need to throw that too:

```
void myMethod() throws InputMismatchException, IOException {
    // your code, except 
    throw new InputMismatchException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you throw exception, then there is no need to try-catch-finally it. try catch finally is necessary when you catch an exception. try the following--

```
if (x.length == Styles.size()) {

    }
    else{
         throw new InputMismatchException() ;
    }
```

Comment: He needs to close his scanner to keep from having resource leaks, so suggesting that he doesn't need this is completely incorrect.

Comment: I was commenting w.r.t. of exception handling. obviously he needs to free the resource. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of the exception then throw it. `throws` is used as part of a method declaration, not to actually throw the exception.

```
    if (x.length == Styles.size()) {

    }
    else{
         throw new InputMismatchException();
    }
```